# Linkedin Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, angular, linkedin-api

I am trying to call an API to get user information but its always giving me this error: `Could not find person based on: ~`, below is my code to call the `people` API:

```
IN.API.Raw('/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,maiden-name,headline,location,industry,picture-url,summary,specialties,positions,picture-urls::(original),email-address,num-connections,site-standard-profile-request,api-standard-profile-request,public-profile-url)?format=json').result((data) => {
   callback(data);
}).error((error) => {
   console.log('Error:', error);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried with only a couple of fields to see if you have the same error?

Comment: yeah already did that but no luck...